# Displaying List Collection to the textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, textbox

I have this class for Student

```
#region Person

    public class Person
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public virtual void GetInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0}", firstName);
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0}", lastName);
            Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", Address);
        }
    }
    #endregion
    class

    #region Student
    public class Student : Person
    {

        public override void GetInfo()
        {
            // Calling the base class GetInfo method: 
            base.GetInfo();
        }
        public void TakeTest()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }



        private List<Student> AllStudents = new List<Student>();
        public Student()
        {
            AllStudents.Add(this);

        }
        public List<Student> AllStudentsList
        {
            get
            {
                return AllStudents;
            }
            set
            {
                AllStudents = value;
            }
        }


    }
    #endregion
```

Using WPF, I am going to initiate several students to be inputted in a textbox, first name has its textbox and last name has its textbox also, and create a list collection to store these student objects. I created an event handler to add students to the list collection newStudent.

```
public List<Student> newStudent = new List<Student>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCreateStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            student.lastName = txtLastName.Text;
            newStudent.Add(student);

            txtFirstName.Text = "";
            txtLastName.Text = "";

        }
```

My problem is when I try to display it back to the textbox (another event handler) what is stored in the list, the result is not what I expect like first name and last name. How should I implement it to give me the First Name and Last Name of the initiated student.

As a background, since my reputation did not pass the quota to post a picture, everytime I input on the textbox, I click the Create Student button that will add the student name to the list collection. After several students created, I would like them to display  the last element in the list to the textbox when I press another button(let's say we call it btnPrevious. I hope someone can help me on this.

This is my another event handler that will display all students in the list.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Student student = new Student();
            //foreach (Student i in student.AllStudentsList)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(i.Name);
            //}
            //MessageBox.Show(student.AllStudentsList[0].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the names in the textboxes, you should remove these lines from your _Click handler:

```
txtFirstName.Text = "";
txtLastName.Text = "";
```

As for displaying the list of Students, it wasn't clear from your question if you're using a separate control for that. I'm not sure that you want to display a list of users with just one textbox control for each name part. Please clarify.

If all you're wanting is to display the first and last names in the textboxes after you've already retrieved a single Student (in your "other handler"), you just want:

```
txtFirstName.Text = student.firstName;
txtLastName.Text = student.lastName;
```

[Update] Here are a couple of helper functions to display a student and all students. You can modify these to work with any controls you choose to use to display the user information. Put these in your Student class.

```
public void PrintStudent()
{
    int i = AllStudents.Count - 1; //last student
    Student thisStudent = this.AllStudents[i];
    string fName = thisStudent.firstName;
    string lName = thisStudent.lastName;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}. {1} {2}", i+1, fName, lName));
}

public void DisplayAll(List<Student> someStudents)
{
    StringBuilder formattedStudents = new StringBuilder();
    int lastIndex = someStudents.Count - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < someStudents.Count; i++)
    {                
        if (i == 0)
        {
            formattedStudents.AppendLine("Complete List of Students:");                    
        }
        string fName = someStudents[i].firstName;
        string lName = someStudents[i].lastName;
        formattedStudents.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}. {1} {2}", i + 1, fName, lName));

        if (i == lastIndex)
        {
            formattedStudents.AppendLine();
            formattedStudents.AppendLine("Have a nice day.");
        }

    }
    Console.Write(formattedStudents);
}
```

Now, in your handler (or in my case, the Main of my little test console app), you can call them like this:

```
List<Student> listStudents = new List<Student>();

Student first = new Student();
first.firstName = "Mike";
first.lastName = "Smith";

Student second = new Student();
second.firstName = "Joe";
second.lastName = "Murphy";

Student last = new Student();
last.firstName = "Matthew";
last.lastName = "Mahern";

listStudents.Add(first);
listStudents.Add(second);
listStudents.Add(last);

Student lastStudent = listStudents[listStudents.Count - 1]; //return the LAST Student in the list of All Students
lastStudent.PrintStudent();

//now, display all students in the list
lastStudent.DisplayAll(listStudents);
```

Comment: I'm using a different push button for the display of the list.

Comment: Please find updates to my answer. I hope that helps you reach a working solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Before to choose students you need preview them, for this you need to use ListBox or ListView.

```
    // Use ObservableCollection for store and preview data in view controls (see more MVVM)
    public ObservableCollection<Student> newStudents = new ObservableCollection<Student>(); 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyListBox.ItemsSource = newStudents; // MyListBox you may create in code or using XAML
    }
```

Use SelectionChanged event to get selected students from List control.

```
private void SelectionChangedHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
         Student st = MyListBox.SelectedItem as Student;

         if (st == null) return;

         txtFirstName.Text = st.firstName;
         txtLastName.Text = st.lastName;
}
```

**UPD#1**

Your main problem is bad code logic in Student model class.

1) Your code below demonstrate the logic of a static class, but it is not a static class.

```
private List<Student> AllStudents = new List<Student>();
    public Student()
    {
        AllStudents.Add(this);

    }
    public List<Student> AllStudentsList
    {
        get
        {
            return AllStudents;
        }
        set
        {
            AllStudents = value;
        }
    }
```

2) In your MainWindow code you using a external list newStudent, but refer to an internal class variable AllStudentsList.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Student student = new Student();
        //foreach (Student i in student.AllStudentsList)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(i.Name);
        //}
        //MessageBox.Show(student.AllStudentsList[0].ToString());
    }
```

Collection student.AllStudentsList is empty because never used. Try use this code.

```
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(newStudent == null) MessageBox.Show("Students collection is null.");
        foreach (Student i in newStudent)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("First name: {0} Last name: {1}", i.firstName, i.lastName));
        }
        //MessageBox.Show(student.AllStudentsList[0].ToString());
    }
```